# Acquire command output in a file from remote Lotus Domino server

Tags: windows-server-2008, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I have few **Lotus Domino 8.5.3 FP6** Mail Server Application installed on Windows 2008 R2 OS in my company. Currently I uses Lotus Domino Admin client GUI to access servers for admin purposes.
Is there any way I can acquire various command output in a file by using some batch/bash/cmd scripts commands remotely?Example I want to get output of command "tell sav info" from my MAILSRV01 , using my workstation cmd ? 
I tried the command [nserver.exe -c "tell sav info"] or other commands, but it never return any output.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right way already. you can redirect any output of a console command to a file exactly as you do it in cmd.

Your command would simply be:

```
nserver.exe -c "tell sav info >C:\outputsav.txt"
```

BUT: an even better way to monitor a domino server is to use SNMP. With snmp configured you can directly read a lot ov variables, and I am quite sure, that SAV has a lot of SNMP- variables that give you the same information as tell sav info does, without having to parse an output file.

In order to setup SNMP you need to:

- Install Windows SNMP service
- Install Domino SNMP service (lnsnmp -Sc from domino directory)
- Start services collect, quryset, intrcpt.

All of that steps are describved in the admin help (e.g. [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_COMPLETING_SNMP_CONFIGURATION.html))

Comment: SNMP is already enabled on lotus domino and I can fetch many useful information from it as I documented here.  https://aacable.wordpress.com/tag/lotus-domino-snmp 
but the issue is there are many things which cannot be queried y SNMP.
example I have symantec mail security for domino and using its command  `tell sav info` it shows all the stats like spams detection number etc, so i want to catch that numbers remotely to plot it in mrtg.

Comment: The nserver.exe command never return any thing either on prompt or in file.